# How can I add the filename of each used templates and includes in freemarker templates as HTML comments?

Tags: templates, freemarker

Is there a way to configure freemarker so that the Freemarker template engine automatically inserts the name of the current template as an HTML comment?

**Example HTML output I would like to see:**

```
<!-- template file: main.ftl -->
normal template code of the file main.ftl

<!-- template file: myinclude.ftl -->
This is the code from myinclude.ftl
```

I would like to use such functionality for debugging purposes only so that it is easier to find out which HTML fragments where rendered in which template.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `TemplateLoader` implementation that just delegates to another `TemplateLoader` (to the one that you are using when not in debug-mode), but captures the stream that it returns, and inserts the HTML comment after the `<#ftl ...>` directive. (But don't add line-break to the comment, or else it will offset the line number in error messages; use `${'\n'}<!-- ... -->${'\n'}` instead.)